# Spring Boot 2.2.6 Java Application executes sql query on wrong database

Tags: spring-boot, docker, hibernate, maven-2, java-11

I will try to explain the problem as clean as possible. First let me give your some details.

1. We have two seperate repositories set up for two different databases: one Postgres, one MsSQL.
2. We assume to have given correct a transactionmanager annotation for this very query, which you can see in the code shared below.

One of the problems is that we recieve a 'ERROR: relation "dbo.sometable" does not exist' error which indicates an execution on the wrong database (postgres) and we confirmed this by checking pg_log.

And here is the bigger problem. The error above does not occur on every build. Each build either executes the query on the "correct" or "wrong" database and this behaviour consists for each container image despite how many time we kill or torture it, it never changes.

Datasource Configuration:

```
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
        import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
        import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
        import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
        import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
        import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
        
        import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
        import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
        import javax.sql.DataSource;
        
        @Profile("!indexer")
        @Configuration
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        @EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryRef",
                               transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerRef",
                               basePackages = { "com.xxx.consumers.handlers.payment.provider.xxx.repository" })
        public class OrganizerDatasourceConfiguration {
        
            @Bean(name = "zzzEntityManager")
            public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("zzzEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
                return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "zzzDataSourceProperties")
            @ConfigurationProperties("zzz.datasource")
            public DataSourceProperties zzzDataSourceProperties() {
                return new DataSourceProperties();
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "zzzDataSource")
            @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "zzz.datasource.tomcat")
            public DataSource zzzDataSource() {
                return zzzDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class).build();
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "zzzEntityManagerFactory")
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean zzzEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                                        @Qualifier("zzzDataSource") DataSource organizerDataSource) {
                return builder.dataSource(zzzDataSource)
                              .packages("com.xxx.consumers.handlers.zzz")
                              .persistenceUnit("organizer")
                              .build();
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "zzzTransactionManager")
            public PlatformTransactionManager zzzTransactionManager(
                    @Qualifier("zzzEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory zzzEntityManagerFactory) {
                return new JpaTransactionManager(zzzEntityManagerFactory);
            }
        }
```

pom.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>

            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>consumers</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.1</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>

            <properties>
                <elasticsearch.version>7.8.0</elasticsearch.version>
                <java.version>11</java.version>
                <legacy-data.version>3.0.0</legacy-data.version>
                <spring.boot.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
                <jackson.version>2.8.7</jackson.version>
                <postgre.version>42.2.5</postgre.version>
                <spring.rabbitmq.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</spring.rabbitmq.version>
                <asynchttpclient.version>2.5.4</asynchttpclient.version>
                <redisson.version>3.12.2</redisson.version>
                <lombok.version>1.18.2</lombok.version>
                <mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
                <forcerest.version>0.0.40</forcerest.version>
                <hibernate-type.version>2.3.0</hibernate-type.version>
                <mssqlserver.version>8.2.2.jre11</mssqlserver.version>
                <janino.version>3.0.6</janino.version>
                <logstash-logback.version>5.2</logstash-logback.version>
                <maven.compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler-plugin.version>
                <google.cloud.version>1.111.2</google.cloud.version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${google.cloud.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
                    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
                    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
                </dependency>
               
                <!-- SPRING-BOOT -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>${postgre.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.frejo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>force-rest-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${forcerest.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
                    <version>${asynchttpclient.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
                    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-type.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                    <version>${logstash-logback.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${mssqlserver.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                    <version>${janino.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- TEST -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxx-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>

            <build>
                <finalName>consumers</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            

            <distributionManagement>
                <snapshotRepository>
                    <id>xxx-snapshots</id>
                    <url>:snapshot-url</url>
                </snapshotRepository>
                <repository>
                    <id>xxx-releases</id>
                    <url>:release-url</url>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>

            <profiles>
                <profile>
                    <id>sonar</id>
                    <activation>
                        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                   
                    <build>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </build>
                </profile>
            </profiles>


        </project>
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface OpportunityPaymentInstallmentRepository extends JpaRepository<OpportunityPaymentInstallment, Long> {

    @Transactional(value = "organizerTransactionManager", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    Optional<OpportunityPaymentInstallment> getByPaymentInstallmentId(Long paymentInstallmentId);

}
```

Comment: Can you shrink it to just a small amount (i.e. just the amount that throws the error) so that it's much less daunting and much more readable?